# How to validate a specific format phone number?

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

My numbers looks like **(###) ###-####**

There is a space between the ) and the next digit
or my number can look like **(###) ###-#### ext ####**

space after the ext and the )

Can someone tell me what regex needs to be performed to verify if either one is valid. Please note that the extension needs to be 4 digits if one is present.

I found this RegEx expression on the web

```
Regex.Match(number, @"^(\+[0-9]{9})$").Success
```

Unfortunately I am not very good at RegEx to understand or modify that

Comment: "\([0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4} (ext [0-9]{4})?" can be shortened but in some ways its easy to read

Comment: Google libphonenumber: http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as a dupe.  The supposed dupe is much more broad, and this is a very narrow pattern requirement which is actually not even one of the patterns the OP of the supposed dupe specified.  This isn't a question about "how do you validate *any* phone number pattern" as it is "how do you validate this exact series of characters which, oh, by the way, happens to be one example of a phone number".  @poke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this pattern:

```
@"^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}( ext \d{4}){0,1}$"
```